# filtered list of item state not displaying properly

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, state

I have created a list with a bunch of items, each with a bookmark button that toggles a state !saved.  I am trying to create a separate list that only shows the bookmarked items.  When I filter the full list of items on !saved, it works correctly for adding new items.  However, when I remove a saved state from an item, the list ends up deleting the last added item rather than the item I specified.  There are similar issues when I try to re-add a previously removed item.

Is my approach to create this filtered list completely wrong?  Is there a better way?

Here is my toggled state code:

```
<ion-item ng-class="{'save': item.save}" collection-repeat="item in items" ui-sref="tab.page({id:item.$id})">
  <button class="icon button top-right" ng-click="item.save = !item.save" ng-class="{'ion-ios-heart button-clear button-assertive':item.save, 'ion-ios-heart-outline  button-clear button-stable':!item.save}"></button>
</ion-item>
```

Here is my filtered list code:

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item collection-repeat="item in items | filter: !item.save"></ion-item>
</ion-list>
```